# What is different way to store order item and item can have sub item?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

The application has order and an order can have items.
For it we had database tables like following.

```
Table 1 - T_ORDER(pk_order_id, order_no, date)
Table 2 - T_ORDER_ITEM (pk_order_itemid, fk_order_id, ean, quantity, price)
```

Now we have to support the case that order can have bundle item means one bundle item contain more than one real item. A bundle item will have all the property that an normal item can have like ean, quantity, price.

Basically bundle is virtual group of one or more real item but it can have property like real item like quantity - so user can place order more than one such bundle item, ean - for identification, price - it can have price including all real item in the bundle.

I wish to know best database table design to support this case? and what are advantage and disadvantage of one over another and which points should I consider during selecting one of them?

```
Option 1 - New tables for bundle and bundle item
           In addition of above two tables , we add two new tables like
           T_ORDER_BUNDLE(pk_order_bundle_id, fk_order_id, ean, quantity, price
           T_ORDER_BUNDLE_ITEM (pk_order_bundle_itemid, fk_order_bundle_id, ean, quantity, price) 

Option 2 - New table to store bundle and use existing table for item
           T_ORDER_BUNDLE(pk_order_bundle_id, fk_order_id, ean, quantity, price
           Just add new column like fk_order_bundle_id in T_ORDER_ITEM table.

Option 3 - New table to store sub items of an item 
           Bundle item can be stored in existing T_ORDER_ITEM table.
           New table - T_ORDER_ITEM_SUBITEM(pk_order_item_subitem, fk_order_itemid, ean, quantity, price)
```

Note :-
We do not have any master table for items.  Table T_ORDER_ITEM contain all item data and relation to order. As order can accepted for any item and we don't have any fixed list of items to sale.

Comment: There are some things that I don't understand: (1)  Does EAN stand for European Article Number? If so, why isn't it stored in the item table, but in the order_item table? (2) Can an order either only contain normal items or only bundle items? (3) Why are there ean, quantity, and price in the order_bundle table? (4) Can I imagine a bundle item like a PC set, where the raw items are PC, monitor and keyboard for instance? If so, does the bundle item consist of items in the item table?

Comment: 1) Yes, It is stored in order item table like T_ORDER_ITEM. 2) Order can contain any number of only bundle item, only normal item or both. 3) A bundle item can have these properties like ean, quantity and price. 4)Yes, This is the main question here .

Comment: I've posted an answer. As to (1): What I consider strange is that you say the EAN is in the order_item table and not in the item table. Does the EAN change from order to order? Shouldn't it rather be an item attribute independent from any order?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with item bundles, where for example the bundle is a tennis racket set consisting of three items: two rackets and one ball. You have considered three approaches on how to model this in your database. I'm proposing a fourth way.

What you have so far:

- items (item_id, ean, description, list_price)
- orders (order_id, order_no, date)
- order_item (order_item_id, order_id, item_id, quantity, price)

This is what the item table may look like:

```
item_id | ean     | description      | list_price
--------+---------+------------------+-----------
1       | 1234567 | tennis racket    |      50.00
2       | 2345678 | tennis ball      |       4.00
```

Now there is two things we need: A bundle item for the tennis set and the assignment which items belong to the set.

First let's add the bundle item to the item table:

```
item_id | ean     | description      | list_price
--------+---------+------------------+-----------
1       | 1234567 | tennis racket    |      50.00
2       | 2345678 | tennis ball      |       4.00
3       | 3456789 | tennis set       |      98.00
```

The set price 98 is cheaper than the sum of the set's content 50 + 50 + 4 = 104, which is often the reason to buy a set.

Now, for the association we create an association table we can call `bundles` or something alike. It shows which item contains which other items and how many of these.

- bundles (bundle_item_id, bundled_item_id, amount)

And then let's fill it with our data:

```
bundle_item_id | bundled_item_id | amount
---------------+-----------------+-------
3              | 1               |      2
3              | 2               |      1
```